# No VueJS tab in Firefox developer tools

Tags: firefox, vuejs2

The Vue tab doesn't pop up in the Firefox developer tools anymore.

It doesn't work on any site which uses Vue (in dev mode) also.

I already tried enabling and disabling this and all other addons and it doesn't work too.

Does somebody know what is causing this behavior or/and how can I solve it?.

I'm using Xubuntu 64bit Firefox 58.0.1.

More info about this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/366#issuecomment-365207139

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you're self-answering a question, the question must still follow the site's quality standards.  You haven't actually asked a question, and this isn't a blog site.

Comment: I have an idea about the site's quality standards for questions cause I've been an active user for a while, but if you can show me a meta post to see what I can do to improve the question I will apreciate it. I edited the description to add the question sentence maybe it was not so implicint as I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the dist cdn "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js" instead of the regular cdn "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue".

Comment: How and why does that make a difference? Is it a bug in Vue or the devtools? Does it only work for that specific version?

Comment: maybe this should not be downvoted. Sometimes answering one's questions is helpful but if it was me, I wouldn't answer in the same second as the time of the question. Maybe let someone try first, they might know the answer too

Comment: @samayo a self-answered question is not in itself a problem, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. If other people have other answers they can still post them.

Comment: I know that. I'm not just a fan of asking and answering literally on the same second. I would rather wait to see someone answer it first

Comment: @samayo well that's up to you, but there is literally a checkbox provided in the UI to allow people to post Q and A simultaneously

Comment: @samayo , I think it is useful sometimes too and in this case I've been receiving several emails notification about this issue. I just answered at the same second cause the site gave me that chance even when I found weird posting the awnser of my own question(cause it was a question once). But in order to be as fair as I can I haven't chosen my awnser as acepted yet, maybe someone else has a better one and I still can have positive votes from my question (which I first checked if it was asked here).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm really sorry but I don't have more information about this regard. Just managed to solve the situation for me, you can see other users description too by clicking on the git-hub link provided above. Let's see if someone else come up with a better description or solution for this issue cause the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I fixed this issue via following methods:

1. Close all Vue.js websites
2. Close DevTools
3. Disable Vue.js DevTools add-on
4. Enable DevTools again
5. Open DevTools